# What is isDebuggerConnected() used for?

Tags: java, android

Is

> isDebuggerConnected()

used to detect if I, as a developer, is debugging or if third party is debugging?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the android docs:

> isDebuggerConnected
>   Added in API level 1
>
> public static boolean isDebuggerConnected ()
>
> Determine if a debugger is currently attached.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#isDebuggerConnected()

So it just means its true if the debugger is attached to the application you are running.